# GCC -Wshadow missing some cases?

Tags: c++, gcc

I saw another post about GCC -Wshadow being too strict. My problem is the opposite.

I revisited some code I'd written and noticed -Wshadow did not work as I expect:

```
void free(double* x) {
    free(x);
}
```

Or:

```
#include <string.h>
// other code here
int memset = 0;
```

Both compile with no warnings with -Wshadow. I believe the usual way is:

```
::free(x) // for 1st example
::log(x) // when in doubt if it's my function or the log from math.h
```

However, ideally I'd like to have -Wshadow catch these. I don't think I am understanding GCC or c++ correctly. Could someone please explain why it works this way, and should it? Thank you.

I compile all my code with:

```
GCC-4.8.2 -static-libstdc++ -std=c++11 -pedantic -Werror -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Wold-style-cast
```

**Edited in reply to comments below** about overloading: I can also compile

```
void free(void* x) {
    // blah
}
```

It doesn't look like overloading now, matching exact signature of the C library one. But I think the compiler needs to warn (-Wshadow) in this case. About memset: I'm not actually writing code as blatant as the memset case, but I'm giving it as an example.

**Edit2** Example link: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/8v2M1i1-Dls
In this link's post, you cannot declare symbols like "abs" with -Wshadow. Yet I can declare symbols like "memset", "free", etc. GCC site says -Wshadow should warn when built-ins are shadowed.

Comment: `free(x);` doesn't shadow anything. Your function itself would be overloaded if it's in the same scope as the library one.

Comment: `memset` is the name of a function from the standard `C` library, you are really asking for troubles here.

Comment: `free(static_cast<void*>(x))` is the way to... (when using `free`...)

Comment: @user2485710: that's why OP wants a warning for that... Hoping `-Wshadow` do that.

Comment: chris, I changed my free to match the signature of the library one. I still don't get a warning. I still don't see why -Wshadow should not warn on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shadowing warnings are targeted at situations when: 1) the name hiding occurs, i.e. one name is hidden by another name declared later or in a more local scope, 2) the code is still well-formed.

In case of your `free`, if the declaration is made in global namespace, then you have overloading, not shadowing. (I can't say right away whether this attempt to "extend" the standard library is actually legal.) In case of your `memset`, again if the declaration is made in global namespace, the declaration is simply illegal, i.e. the code is invalid.

As for contexts when genuine name hiding actually happens... You see, `-Wshadow` is intended to be a *warning* - something that is intended to catch potentially dangerous name hiding in formally *perfectly legal* code. As is always the case with warnings, in order to avoid making it overly zealous and annoying its developers had to somehow separate all name hiding situations into those that look really suspicious and those which are likely to be intentional. For this specific warning, I'd say that it would make sense to warn when hiding happens between entities of similar nature: a type hides another type, a function hides another function and a variable hides another variable. When *entities of the same nature* hide each other, there is a great potential for error: the user might use one entity while believing they use the other, and the code will still quietly compile. But when entities of *different* natures hide each other, the need to warn is greatly reduced, since entities of different nature have quite different usage contexts/patterns/syntaxes. For example, variable usage syntax is usually different from function usage syntax (this is not entirely accurate, of course, if we consider function objects, but still largely true). Any accidental misuse will likely be caught by the compiler as an error. For this reason, it is probably a good idea *not* to issue a shadowing warning when, say, a variable hides a function or a function hides a type. This is probably why you get no warning from `-Wshadow` when a local `memset` *variable* hides the global `memset` *function*. If you accidentally miss or forget about the local `int memset;` declaration and continue to use `memset` as if it were a function (`memset(dst, src, n)`) the code will simply fail to compile. No need for any extra warnings here, since your error will most definitely be caught and reported anyway.

**UPDATE:** In your additional case with `free` declared as `void free(void *)`, i.e. fully matching the standard function signature, you are dealing with one of gcc "features". You are actually providing your own definition of a standard library function, which *replaces* the "standard" definition. Specifically to give you that opportunity all standard library functions in GCC library implementation are declared as so called *weak symbols*. This is a useful feature in some cases (as a debugging aid and such), but the price we have to pay for it is that it becomes possible to *accidentally* replace a standard function.

Whether `-Wshadow` is supposed to warn about this is a different question... Again, `-Wshadow` was introduced to warn about dangerous name hiding. In this case there's no name hiding and, formally, the code is illegal. But GCC allows it for the purposes outlined above.

Comment: plus `#include <string.h>` is the wrong way to include that header.

Comment: @user2485710: I'm only trying to illustrate that memset is included. I know the newer c++ standards say to drop the ".h".

Comment: @AndreyT. Yes it's invalid/bad. But why is it compiling fine on GCC? That's my question in this post. (Please see my post for GCC flags).

Comment: @user3361645 considering your original post you really have no use for `-Wshadow`, the errors are somewhere else in those lines of code. Regarding why this compiles, even code that cause _undefined behaviour_ still compile fine on most compilers, the compiler simply can't detect all possible errors, especially if your program is ill-formed.

Comment: @user3361645: I have no idea why it compiles in your case. My GCC immediately reports `error: ‘int memset’ redeclared as different kind of symbol` for your `memset` declaration.

Comment: @AndreyT are you compiling this with `gcc` or `g++` ? because both my `g++ 4.8.1` and `clang++ 3.5 from the svn trunk` do not show any kind of errors or warnings .

Comment: @AndreyT. You are right, I missed where you wrote "in global namespace". Your error comes from "-Wextra".

I agree with everything you said. But it doesn't answer my question of, did -Wshadow miss a case? So there's 1) Am I understanding -Wshadow incorrectly 2) Is it missing a case. Wshadow is supposed to catch it when it's in 2 different scopes (memset in global shadowed by memset in my local scope.) It's not undefined. I can do math with my integer memset and it's fine.

Even if I'm not overloading, as I edited in the post, I am still getting no warning. Now it's shadow, not overloading.

Comment: @user3361645 rule of thumb: if 2 or more compilers agree, showing the same behaviour, an error from your part it's more likely than any "missing" feature or bug. Your program is ill formed, that's it, Why you want `-Wshadow` to do this kind of work if it's not supposed to do that ? plus using names from the standard library, in both `C` and `C++` is a really bad habit anyway.

Comment: @user2485710: so if no phones out there can surf the web, I can't ask if we should make one that does that? Your logic means there cannot be innovation or improvement to existing tools.

Comment: @user3361645 this is not a symposium , you asked for something that it's not there, you want to improve `gcc` or `clang` or whetever, good, they are even opensource projects, you can do it. You want to contribute to the language specs or the standard library, go for the c++ forum where they discuss this stuff.

Comment: @user2485710: if you want to come in and talk about other things not related to my question (all your posts) you need to leave this thread too. I'm asking a legit question and you wanted to talk about my #include and other unrelated things to Wshadow.

Comment: @AndreyT: Thank you! I think this makes sense to me. I will read up about weak symbols and be more careful about this case.